# Looking into Maltese ancestry?

Tags: getting-started, malta

My dad is Maltese (from Malta) and I cannot seem to find much information, at least not in my free research so far.

Where should I start?

I'm looking for my dad's family's names really, not interested in details for now. I'd like to focus on the direct male line of descent through my father's father and see how far I can get. Therefore, I'm looking for birth certificates at this point primarily, and since I know name's up to my great-grandfather I will be starting from around late 1920's/early 30's.

Comment: Hi Charlie, this question is too broad at the moment. Can you please specify what type of information you are looking for (i.e. finding a certain record) or what problem you are trying to solve (finding father's parents names)? Also please specify a rough date as the question will no doubt have a different answer for the 1960s vs 1780s.

Comment: @HarryVervet 'tis done

Comment: If you already know your great grandfather's name and birth year, then I think the next step would be to try and identify his birth family (i.e. siblings and parents).  If he was born after 1917 please do not post his name and birth details unless you are also able to post a link to evidence of decease - see our privacy policy in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @PolyGeo this is what I did for my Scottish ancestry on my mother's side, which was really easy to find. Problem is in Malta they don't seem to have the same kind of online database from what I can find and not to mention a lot of records were destroyed in WW2

Comment: G&FH is much easier to undertake in some countries than in others. Consequently, you may need to take each step much more carefully for Malta than you did for Scotland in order to glean what you can from surviving clues.

Comment: Do you know your great grandfather's birth date/year? Do you know of any siblings? Do you know anything about him besides his name and that he came from Malta?

Comment: @PolyGeo He was a postman I believe, his wife is called Rena (don't know her maiden name though I can ask as she is still alive and well in Melbourne). They would have married sometime in the 40's or 50's and he emigrated to Australia in the 2000's. His birth year would have been 1925 give or take 5 years.

Comment: @PolyGeo just found out he died in 2014 in Melbourne at the age of 86 meaning he would have been born in 1928 or 1927

Comment: If you were able to ask his widow if she knew the names of his parents and/or siblings then I think that would be very helpful to you. With his widow being alive we need you to be very mindful of our privacy policy in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @PolyGeo I will check the privacy policy. Thank you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was in the same boat as you are about 10 years ago... There was barely anything on the internet, but persistence paid off and over the 10 years I have found sites here and there that have helped me get to where I am today. I started with just up to my great grandparents and today I have gone as far back as the 1500s!

I actually came across this post as I haven't 'googled' in a while to see if I can find something new on the ancestors.

Anyway, I have a blog where I record my journey and I have a page with a list of sites I found useful along the way: https://missmalta.wordpress.com/links/ Feel free to check it out... When I first started and persisted, I used to come across a couple of blogs that inspired me to keep going, so hopefully, mine might just do that for you. The links page though, I think you will find very useful.

In answer to your question though... If you are wanting just some names to climb up the tree, if you know your grandfather/great grandfather's name(s) and DOB, you can order their birth/marriage/death certificates from this site: https://secure2.gov.mt/certifikati/department.aspx on the certificates they will have the parents names and their occupation... That will then give you a lead to go back further up the tree.

Also, as others have suggested, speaking to any living relatives that may have any information to help you go back is a BIG help. Names, DOBs... Anything - this will assist immensely!

I didn't get too far with this because unfortunately, they won't have the DOB of the parents on the certificates. And my grandparents have all passed away, my parents didn't have too much info that could help me. When I visited Malta I went to the village church and they had record of the births/marriages/deaths. From there we kept going back.

With all those names I could then sit on the net and google each name til I got a lead... Which I did and the things I found were mind blowing!

Now if you aren't visiting Malta anytime soon, you could do 2 things;

1. Get in touch with a Maltese genealogist (I live in Australia, I know of one I can recommend here, there's another one in Malta that I can suggest) or
2. Email the Public Registry in Malta (or Gozo specifically if your family is from there) and they may be able to assist.  Email them as many details as you can give them and they should be able to put you into some kind of a lead.

Answer (score 3):

A good starting point is often the FamilySearch [Research Wiki](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Main_Page) page for the place you are interested in.

In this case, the page for [Malta genealogy](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Malta_Genealogy) has links to further information on civil registration in Malta with the appropriate contact addresses.

The page also contains links to a variety of other sources of information that may be useful to you as you progress with your research.

Answer (score 0):

Many ressources are available, the main one are :

- [Malta baptisms index](https://en.geneanum.com/malta/databases/baptisms.html)
- [Malta marriages index](https://en.geneanum.com/malta/databases/marriage.html)
- [Malta deaths index](https://en.geneanum.com/malta/databases/burials.html)
- [Digitized archives](https://www.maltaparisharchives.org/catalog)
- [Order certificate](https://secure2.gov.mt/certifikati/department.aspx)